# $x^4-3x^2+4$ irreducible over over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> I need to prove irreducibility of $x^4-3x^2+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>   It can't have any linear factor since it doesn't have any root in $\mathbb{Q}$ because any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a root only if $\alpha|4$ i.e. only possibility for $\alpha=\pm1,\pm2,\pm4$ but none of them is a root. But how shall I prove that it can't have quadratic factor over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Assume it can be factored as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and reach a contradiction. You still need to justify why I took monic polynomials.

Comment: Ah, don't forget to use Gauss's lemma so you can take $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hint: Since all the powers are even, it would have to factor as $(x - \alpha)(x - \overline{\alpha})(x - \beta)(x - \overline{\beta})$ over $\mathbb{C}$.  This can make the computation suggested by @GitGud a bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^2-3x^2+4=(x^2+2)^2-7x^2=(x^2-\sqrt{7}\,x+2)(x^2+\sqrt{7}\,x+2)$ is the decomposition into irreducible factors over $\mathbb{R}$.